# Wrapping python dictionary or set onto new line

Tags: python, string, dictionary, newline, string-length

I am trying to find a way to print the values in a dict so that after a certain length (5 for example) the set breaks and continues on a new lines.

**Example:**

```
dict = {'Upper':'ABCDEFGHI', 'Lower':'abcdefghi', 'Number':'123456789'}

def insertNewlines(text, lineLength):
    if len(text) <= lineLength:
        return text
    else:
        return text[:lineLength] + '\n' + insertNewlines(text[lineLength:], lineLength)

for key, val in dict.items():
    print(insertNewlines(val,5))
```

**Output**

```
ABCDE
FGHI
abcde
fghi
12345
6789
```

**Desired Output:**

```
ABCDE
abcde
12345

FGHI
fghi
6789
```

Comment: Output from what? Are you printing or just typing it in the shell?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question since it is unclear/ambiguous. The two most likely meanings are both practically trivial, and almost certainly duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

`pprint` can be used to print a dictionary (or an array among many datatypes) to the console:

```
import pprint

dictionary = {}
dictionary['x'] = 'xyz'
dictionary['y'] = 'abc'
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(width=5)
pp.pprint(dictionary)
```

This prints:

```
{'x': 'xyz',
 'y': 'abc'}
```

It also has other options such as indenting. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly straightforward with some functions to help out:

```
def chunk(s, size):
    return [s[i:i+size] for i in range(1 + len(s) / size)]

def wrapped(info, size):
    values = info.values()
    chunks = [chunk(v, size) for v in values]
    groups = zip(*chunks)
    return '\n\n'.join('\n'.join(g) for g in groups)
```

With your example:

```
>>> info = {'Upper':'ABCDEFGHI', 'Lower':'abcdefghi', 'Number':'123456789'}
>>> print wrapped(info, 5)
ABCDE
abcde
12345

BCDEF
bcdef
23456
```

If you want to deal with line lengths that don't match:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def wrapped(info, size):
    values = info.values()
    chunks = [chunk(v, size) for v in values]
    groups = izip_longest(*chunks)
    return '\n\n'.join('\n'.join(filter(None, g)) for g in groups)
```

you can get results like this:

```
ABCDE
abcde
12345

BCDEF
bcdef
23456

cdefg

defgh
```

and if you want the rows to line up

```
    groups = izip_longest(*chunks, fillvalue='')
    return '\n\n'.join('\n'.join(g) for g in groups)
```

gives

```
ABCDE
abcde
12345

BCDEF
bcdef
23456


cdefg



defgh
```